# Will chunks in transform streams break replace attempts?

Tags: node.js, replace, stream, chunks

I use transform streams in Node JS to replace keywords in a large textfile on the fly with data, mostly to save RAM. The file looks something like this.

```
datadatadatadata{{replace_here}}datadatadatadata{{replace_there}}datadatada
```

Everything is working fine so far, but I am rather new to using streams and there is a question bothering me.

As far as I understand, the data entering the transform stream is split into chunks, so there will be a cut somewhere between let's say the first and second chunk. That is fine when it looks like this.

```
Chunk 1 [datadatadatadata{{replace_here}}datadata]
Chunk 2 [datadata{{replace_there}}datadatada]
```

What I am wondering is, whether there is a chance that there will be only a part of that keword (**{{repl**) in the first chunk and the other part (**ace_here}}**) in the second chunk?

```
Chunk 1 [datadatadatadata{{repl]
Chunk 2 [ace_here}}datadatadatadata{{replace_th]
Chunk 3 [ere}}datadatada]
```

That would mean something like

```
chunk.toString().replace('{{replace_here}}', 'datadatadata');
```

would fail, because there is only **{{repl** in the chunk, right? Have I just been lucky until now that the keywords were not cut between two chunks? Are transform streams suitable for replacing things like this, or should I do something else?